# A closing bracket was expected near ()

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTs `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `firs_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `sign_up_date` date (255) NOT NULL,
    `activated` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY `id`
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: `sign_up_date date (255) NOT NULL,` should be `sign_up_date date NOT NULL,`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:    `sign_up_date` date (255) NOT NULL

When you refer to date you don't set the maximum of characters.

Try:    `sign_up_date` date NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTs `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `firs_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `sign_up_date` date NOT NULL,
    `activated` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY `id`
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```